# Tsql ordering data by specific string values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an audit table that have data for insert, update and delete operations. I am writing a report that will display data in the order of Insert, Update and Delete. I don't think the order by clause will help. any help?

Answer (score 12):

You can use an ORDER BY combined with a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM auditlog
ORDER BY CASE operation_type
    WHEN 'Insert' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Update' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Delete' THEN 3
END
```