# SQL order by multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with 'name','status'-fail or success,'counts'- 1 to 100. I want to order it in such a way that names of only 'fail' should show on top together, then same name with fail and success together, then names with only success together.
Can we do it sql query language ?
Thank you.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758374/tsql-ordering-data-by-specific-string-values Basically you can `ORDER BY` using a `CASE` statement, followed by name and counts.

Comment: And you are using MySQL or SQL Server? (and wich version?)

Comment: What 'together' means according to you? What influence does 'counts' have on your sorting? Best would be to provide an example of data and then an example of an expected result. That would make your question answered way faster. Due to the uniqueness of imagination of each person, I think there can be several different solutions and results, fitting your request though. So yeah, add an example of what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this should work on most RDBMS:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT  name, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT status) StatusCount,
                    MIN(status) MinStatus
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY name) B
    ON A.name = B.name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN StatusCount = 1 AND MinStatus = 'fail' THEN 1
         WHEN StatusCount = 2 THEN 2 
         ELSE 3 END, A.name, A.status
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is MySQL

```
select *, 0 as o
from t
union all
select *, 1 as o
from t
order by
    o = 1 and status != 'fail', o != 1, status = fail
```